# SQL create OR condition from comma delimated string

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I'm having the following table in my database.

[image: MYSQL Table]

I'm firing the below query to get some keywords:

```
SELECT CONCAT('%',replace (keyword, ' ','%'),'%') FROM `ads` WHERE "rent 
car"  LIKE CONCAT('%',replace (keyword, ' ','%'),'%')
```

This is working fine and giving me two results `%car%` and `%rent%car%`

But the query will not be fired for last record as there are two many keywords by comma separated so that I need the same query with multiple or conditions for each comma delimited keyword like below (if there are comma separated strings in a row otherwise it should be same as above):

```
SELECT CONCAT('%',replace (keyword, ' ','%'),'%') FROM `ads` WHERE ("rent 
home"  LIKE '%rent%home%') OR ("rent 
home"  LIKE '%rental%homes%') OR ("rent 
home"  LIKE '%rent%2bhk%') OR ("rent 
home"  LIKE '%rent%3bhk%')
```

I know, I will need a SQL function but could not get such kind of function. How can I do that?

Comment: & what is the keyword, you are passing?

Comment: rent home is the user searching string.

Comment: Are you supporting multi-word searching?

Comment: No, There will be only one keyword at a time

Comment: If there will be only one keyword at-a-time, then %keyword% should work.

Comment: I mean user will search a single keyword but db can have multiple keywords in each row

Comment: Can you create SQL fiddle for it?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you want to search keyword (multi-word) by replacing space with `%`, so that it should match `%pre-word%post-word%`.

e.g. for keyword `rent home`, should search `rent home`, `rental home`, `rental homes` etc

If right, following query should satisfy your requirement:

```
SELECT keyword FROM `ads` WHERE keyword 
LIKE CONCAT('%', replace('rent home', ' ', '%'), '%');
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ceee2/5)